# Using 'few months back' and 'few months ago'

Tags: time

While I have grown up knowing that 'ago' is the word of choice while referring to an earlier timeline.now I have become quite confused with the regular use of 'back' in its place.

Many say that 'ago' sounds better when used in 'many a millennia ago' or 'many years ago', 'back' is more suited while saying 'a couple of months back' or 'a few days back'.

I am, somehow, not convinced. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *back* in this way is grammatical in Standard English, but its use is mainly colloquial.

Comment: And round here, in Yorkshire, _since_ is a third alternative.